# Do some combat checks occur without monsters?

Tags: arkham-horror

Many location encounters reference a monster (such as a monster appearing) and require a combat check.  One encounter at St. Mary's Hospital says

> The corpse you are examining isn't quite dead yet. It reaches out and grabs you by the throat. Lose 1 Sanity. Then you must fight the corpse. If you pass the Combat (-1) check, you defeat it and gain 1 Clue token.  Otherwise, move to the streets

Am I to draw a monster randomly and skip the option to evade here (doesn't seem implied), or am I to simply do a Fight check enhanced by those items that regularly can enhance it during combat (such as 2 hands worth of weapons and other combat enhancing boosts) and then forgo any modifier for the creature's combat rating since there is no creature?

I'm assuming when there is mention of a monster appearing or attacking, and then a reference to a combat check, that normally I would want to draw a random monster as in the various mentions to a monster appearing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't draw a monster. Like you said, you just make a combat check - except there is a modifier, the (-1) specified by the encounter. And it really is a combat check, not a weird fight check; that's why your items with combat modifiers apply.

If a monster is to appear, the card will say so, and plenty do.